# Can't access R class elements

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When cleaning out my Workspace folder for a clearer view in Eclipse, I deleted `android-support-v7-appcompat` project thinking it was a sample code I downloaded a while ago. I figured out it wasn't a wise move and restored it back, importing it from Eclipse. I now have a problem accessing the `R` elements, even in new automatically generated projects. For example accessing the following elements gives a `cannot be resolved or is not a field` error on the last element:
`R.layout.activity_crime`, `R.menu.crime`, `R.id.action_settings`. I tried to rebuild the project, deleting the `gen` folder so `R.java` would regenerate but nothing changes. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: You have an error somewhere in your code. Resolve these errors then you will be able to clean and rebuild your project. Look for hints in the "error list" section.

Comment: Have you set layout in `setContentView()`?

Comment: Yes, There is a call to `setContentView`, but gives an error since the argument is `R.layout.activity_crime`.

Answer (score 1):

A brief aside - it is honestly worth moving over to Android studio. I used eclipse until very recently and so many of these annoying little errors have been resolved.

Few things I used to do to fix this error:

1. Delete R class if it has been generated.
2. Make sure there is no errors in your xml.
3. Clean the project.
4. Make sure your build path is all correct.
5. restart eclipse
6. LAST RESORT: Make a new android project and copy over your code.

Hope this helps. Once again, really recommend AS.

Comment: How can I check if my build path is correct? And the only reason I'm not using Android Studio is because I just started to learn Android programming and I'm following the Big Nerd Ranch Android Programming book which uses Eclipse. I will probably move to AS when I'm done with the basics.

Comment: So check your dependencies are there. For a basic Andorid project this is appcompat and the Java JRE I believe.

Finally, I really do recommend you switch to AS earlier rather than later. I found moving very hard and I am quite experienced. I still press eclipse shortcuts. This guide is great for starting out :http://www.raywenderlich.com/78574/android-tutorial-for-beginners-part-1

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately the answer you gave didn't work for me but switched to Android Studio and try to follow the book from there.

Answer (score 0):

Till you have problem in your "res" folder, R.java class could not be generated.
So try to resolve all problems (in xml files) before.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't show any errors on the XML files, and I don't think there would be any errors in automatically generated files by Eclipse when a new project is created.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, until one of these results in success:

- Look through your XML files for any errors and fix them.
- Clean your project.
- Restart Eclipse.
- Clean again.
- Create a new, clean workspace and import your existing project into it.

As for recreating the workspace – I have myself come across similar issues after messing with some internals, and recreating the workspace was the only way to fix it.